# Deleting a managed visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, visualforce-component

I'm trying to delete a visualforce page that is contained in a managed package. I have opened a case with the Salesforce support team and they enabled deletion of components that are contained in a managed package (I've already deleted some other components).

However, when I go to the visualforce page details, there is no "delete" button, or any method to remove the page.

**Note**: the page is being used as the content of another custom tab that I already deleted, but when clicking "where is this used?" I still get the deleted tab, but cannot edit the content.

Is there a way to delete this visualforce page?

Comment: I might be wrong(and I probably am), but don't deleted items end up in recycle bin for some time? In this case this tab is in recycle bin and not yet fully deleted

Comment: @Novarg tabs are not going to the recycle bin (just double verified it). When deleting the tab you actually agree that the change is irreversible.

Comment: You've probably already explored it, but you don't explicitly mention it, so worth asking: what happened when you tried to delete the managed package? Or are these some components in the package that you want to keep?

Comment: Also, how long ago did you delete the tab. We do very little hard deleting. Often "delete" means "marked for delete at a later time but still recoverable if that was a bad mistake". The consistency check should still allow deletion of the page, but something may have gone wrong given the irregular circumstance of the managed package.

Comment: Is this in your packaging org or is this for a package you have installed in your own org?

Comment: @Peter I can't delete the managed package because it has a released version that cannot be deprecated. So instead I'm trying to delete of its components. The tab was deleted more than two hours ago, and it still appears.

Comment: @MikeChale it's in the packaging org. The package is installed for other orgs as well.

Comment: @Tzach - Have you been able to resolve? I am seeing the same thing. My VF page I have removed ALL content except <apex:page> tags and still have no option to delete. I have logged a case with partner support. Curious though if you got it resolved

Comment: @Eric unfortunately no. I also tried opening a support case and follow their instructions, but after a few weeks of trying, I finally gave up and created a new SF organization with a new package.

Comment: @Tzach - The docs I was reading were apparently Spring 15 docs. So while not available today, it will be in a week! Looking forward to getting rid of some clutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting Spring 2015, VisualForce pages can be deleted even if they are included in a Managed Package. Just go to the VisualForce page details and click `delete`.

Comment: I am not able to see any delete icon in my manage package for vf page.

Comment: @Ankuli Make sure your page doesn't reference other components, plus you might have to ask Salesforce to unlock this feature for you.

Comment: ok. I have made cf page code completely blank. ok. I have to contact sf support for this privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Straight out of [Salesforce Online Help](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_manage.htm)

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the link to the help page?

Comment: The question stated that support has enable a special permission to be able to delete components from the managed package. Are you thinking that somehow this permission doesn't include Visualforce pages even though other items components can be deleted?

Comment: Hi Tzach,Here you go. http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_manage.htm

Comment: @AmitBangad - FYI With the new ability to delete components in a managed package (currently a feature request) you are supposed to be able to remove VF pages now.

Comment: Thanks Eric, it means Salesforce can enable this privilege.Sounds great !

Comment: @AmitBangad - The docs I was reading were apparently Spring 15 docs. So while not available today, it will be in a week!

Comment: Thats one point to me then. Please promote the answer ;)